Typing error with inherited classes having overloaded constructor with different parameters
With the code below:
import abc

class ABCParent(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, a: str, sibling_type: type[ABCParent]) -> None:
        self.a = a
        self._sibling_type = sibling_type
    def new_sibling(self, a: str) -> ABCParent:
        return self._sibling_type(a)

class ChildA(ABCParent):
    def __init__(self, a: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(a, ChildB)

class ChildB(ABCParent):
    def __init__(self, a: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(a, ChildA)

I get the following typing error, using mypy in strict mode.
src/demo_problem.py: note: In member "new_sibling" of class "ABCParent":
src/demo_problem.py:10:16:10:36: error: Missing positional argument "sibling_type" in call to "ABCParent"  [call-arg]
            return self._sibling_type(a)

This is perfectly logical, since ABCParent requests the sibling_type argument. But in my case, the self._sibling_type will be one of the child classes, which override the constructor such that sibling_type is not needed.
I was able to work around the problem by using a typing.Union of the child classes:
import abc
import typing

TConcreteChild: typing.TypeAlias = typing.Union["ChildA", "ChildB"]

class ABCParent(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, a: str, sibling_type: type[TConcreteChild]) -> None:
        ...

But I don't like this because:

It involves defining a type alias (TConcreteChild) which is otherwise useless
The definition of this alias must be updated if more child classes are defined
It involves defining types before definitions of the classes, so it requires forward references using strings (and therefore it can't use the new ChildA | ChildB syntax).

How can I do this more cleanly, while still having strict type checking?

You could pass the class of self  as well, but I'm wondering if you don't have an XY problem here. Why does your __init__ require the sibling_type to begin with? Are you only passing it to store it so you can use it in new_sibling? If so, have you considered making new_sibling a class method instead? Because that would solve the whole problem.

The problem here is that you are incorrectly changing the signature of the __init__ method of the children. You can add parameters, but you cannot remove them.

@chepner never heard about that rule. Why?

It's a static-typing rule, not a Python rule (look up the Liskov Substitution Principle). The violation of the rule here presents itself exactly as you recognized: mypy cannot know that sibling_type really refers to a child class. It can only go by the signature of ABCParent.__init__ itself.

Thanks. But in my logic, a child can be more precise, less flexible, and that’s my approach.
How would you manage those situations better?

So, I think one approach that could work depending on the specifics of your actual use-case is making ._sibling_type a generic callable and making the classes generic as well, parametrized with the same type variable.
import abc
import typing

P = typing.TypeVar("P", bound="ABCParent")

class ABCParent(typing.Generic[P], metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, a: str, sibling_type: typing.Callable[[str], P]) -> None:
        self.a = a
        self._sibling_type = sibling_type
    def new_sibling(self, a: str) -> P:
        return self._sibling_type(a)

class ChildA(ABCParent["ChildB"]):
    def __init__(self, a: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(a, ChildB)

class ChildB(ABCParent["ChildA"]):
    def __init__(self, a: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(a, ChildA)

Types are callables. And in my experience with mypy, treating them like callables when you can is the easier approach.
As an aside, you can still use the pipe operator syntax with string-based forward references, e.g.:
def foo(x: "ChildA | ChildB") -> None:
    ...


Thanks a lot @juanpa. The the last remark, I was writing the "ChildA" | "ChildB" ... stupidly...

You can use typing.overload to allow a signature of ABCParent.__init__ without sibling_type while implementing ABCParent.__init__ with sibling_type required.
This works because presumably ABCParent is never going to be instantiated directly (being an abstract base class), and ABCParent.__init__ is always going to be called with subling_type supplied when new_sibling is called through a child class:
from typing import overload

class ABCParent(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @overload
    def __init__(self, a: str) -> None: ...

    @overload
    def __init__(self, a: str, sibling_type: type[ABCParent]) -> None: ...

    def __init__(self, a, sibling_type):
        self.a = a
        self._sibling_type = sibling_type

    def new_sibling(self, a: str) -> ABCParent:
        return self._sibling_type(a)

class ChildA(ABCParent):
    def __init__(self, a: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(a, ChildB)

class ChildB(ABCParent):
    def __init__(self, a: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(a, ChildA)

Demo: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=bb47ced8b8043a9cce8834ab48e48b62
